# Drag and Drop Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am having an issue with drag and drop in Internet Explorer and Safari. In Firefox 15 (untested on other versions) the code functions properly. Items can be dragged and dropped from one dropzone to another, and sorting in the top dropzone works perfectly. In Safari, dragging and dropping seems to still seems to work, but the sorting does not. In Internet Explorer, nothing works. I want to avoid jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/kMbPF/18/

I am assuming that a way to solve this is covered in this tutorial. One of the issues I am having with this code, is they applied it to only one element, and I have multiple. Also when I applied this to just one element, it made that element draggable, but did not allow it to be dropped in the in dropzone. I am not positive, but this solution only seems to work if Internet Explorer is version 9 or greater, which is not ideal, but definitely better than no support at all. I also do not think that I can do this onload like they did seeing I will be populating my draggable objects from a database, so onload will probably have fired before the items have been placed into the dropzone. http://marakana.com/s/html5_drag_n_drop_api,1071/samples/try2.htm Specifically:

```
if(myDiv.dragDrop){
    myDiv.onselectstart=function(){this.dragDrop();return false};
}
```

I am not trying to attain 100% browser compatibility, but I would like to get Internet Explorer and Firefox. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer prior to 10 doesn't understand the `draggable` attribute.  For drag and drop to work on IE you need the items to be dragged to be something which is innately draggable: a link, an image or selected text.  Change your `table` elements to `a` elements and it will work in IE.